# Kardashev scale of alien civilization in Independence Day?

Tags: independence-day

The [Kardashev scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kardashev_scale) is a way of measuring a hypothetical civilization's ability to harness energy.

This scale has always made me think about the movie Independence Day (1996), my favorite example of a villainous alien civilization.  Dr. Okun claims their technology is far more advanced than ours, and the [evidence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8wTUkn0T_8) bears that out. From what I can tell, the aliens own significant advances in weaponry and transportation, to name just a few areas (yet were somehow completely undone by a few lines of code and a lowly nuke? But I digress...)

Anyways, given what we know about this species and their technology, is there in-universe evidence to suggest if this species might be categorized as Type II or Type III (or higher?) on the Kardashev scale?

Comment: Pretty sure the Harvesters are on a Type I level - able to harness the energy of planets (and smaller bodies). I believe one of the novels (I've only read the first one, but seen quotes from the others) goes more into detail, about how they're literally able to grow their ships from the process of harvesting a planet.

Comment: probably not even a type 1 (all energy on a planetary scale) - can't remember if there was any FTL in the original movie

Comment: @mgh42 not as far as I remember (and I've even read the novel recently). And wormhole travel was the sphere in IDR - the Harvesters just moved through normal means, destroying the outposts as they went.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

Comment: @Vishwa - what's a better network for this question?

Comment: @Will Since you're looking for a species categorizing (biologically or some physical meausrment) rather than a movie based info, I suggest something like 
https://biology.stackexchange.com/ or https://physics.stackexchange.com/.
I may be wrong on the suggested, but categorizing something on Kardashev scale is not movie knowledge.. Hope you find what you looking for...

Comment: @Vishwa You *are* quite wrong. Only on Sci-fi & Fantasy it could be more on topic then here.

Comment: @Mithoron As I've said, I may be wrong on the suggestions.. appreciate the info mate. cheers!

Comment: @Vishwa This is on-topic for this SE site and should *not* be closed since it asks about "analysis of content or theme" of a *movie*. See https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The harvesters are probably a Type 1 civilization

from the scene where the president interacts with the captured alien:

> ```
>           PRESIDENT
>   He wanted me to understand.  He
>   communicated with me.
>       (turning to Grey)
>   They're like locusts.  They travel
>   from planet to planet, their whole
>   civilization.  After they've
>   consumed every natural resource
>   they move on.  And we're next.
> ```

From this description of their behavior  they must have reached the level of type 1

> A Type I civilization, also called a planetary civilization—can use and store all of the energy available on its planet.

There is no evidence of them attempting to harness the energy output of the sun, instead they find another planet to consume.

With no way to know the energy output required for their shields or interstellar travel we can't really judge how far along they are in type 1